# Track a user who has updated data in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am new to Ruby on Rails. The rails application that I have developed has several models including one for user that stores user name, passwords and other user related information.

Now the problem is that a few columns of a table corresponding to a model has modified erratically. Now I want to know if Ralis has any feature so that I can know the user who has done this or this is because of some other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing [Userstamp](https://github.com/delynn/userstamp) and maybe [Paper Trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) to track changes to records. If you've implemented the User model yourself (as opposed to a framework like `devise`), you'll need to read the docs carefully to see what properties are expected of your User models to get the full benefit.

Comment: Yes I have used devise but installed none of those two you told. So I want to know is tracking the user who has done this is possible or not?

Comment: Yes, those plugins will certainly help with that. You can try https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin too to visualise it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)

It adds other columns(yours) in migrate, before generate views

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited might provide the auditing you require.